# Returning to the UK with an expired UK passport

Tags: uk, passports

UK passport expired 29/1/19 on day of travel to Canary Islands, Spain. Thomas Cook airline advised okay for one year at departure gate, thus I am in Spain with an expired passport, but what next for return journey in three weeks time (still to be booked ) Must I apply for an emergency passport for £100 ?
Look forward to hearing from those who may know or advise relevant law ?

Comment: The proposed duplicate features a passport expired *ten years*....

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I don't see why it would make any difference how long ago the passport expired, and the answer clearly states that it doesn't matter, as long as, e.g., the photo is a reasonable likeness. (And one assumes that it is, since it was good enough to get the asker on a plane two days ago.)

Comment: Because the other question is "I have a 10-year-expired british passport but i also have this other passport." While the answer is half relevant to the british side, the questions are distinct.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Thanks, I asked about the expiration date of my passport and validity to travel,  Thomas Cook embarkation gate lady keyed into system , commenting , it’s fine you’ve got a year. That was on 29/1 date of expiration which I only noticed on the day, gov.uk suggests I need a emergency passport at £100, will probably go to airport in Tenerife and ask the ground and immigration staff unless I can find any more help.

Comment: @Gandonas The answer on the other question says you'll be fine using your passport to get back to the UK. If you don't trust that, then you should probably talk to the British consulate in Tenerife.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks for input, you are correct, Im probably best to seek clarification from government sources rather than risking any forum interpretations from ignorant sources.